# How to get value of a variable from another class

Tags: c#, class, surf

I am using Emgu CV's SURF and I used `int j = CvInvoke.cvCountNonZero(mask);`   to find matched pair points.
The problem how to return this value into `main()`?

```
...
...
...
public static Image<Bgr, Byte> Draw(Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage, Image<Gray, byte> observedImage, out long matchTime)      
{
    HomographyMatrix homography;
    VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
    VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
    Matrix<int> indices;
    Matrix<byte> mask;

    FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, out indices, out mask, out homography);

    //Draw the matched keypoints
    Image<Bgr, Byte> result = Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints, indices, new Bgr(255, 255, 255), new Bgr(255, 255, 255), mask, Features2DToolbox.KeypointDrawType.DEFAULT);

    int j = CvInvoke.cvCountNonZero(mask);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple result object:

```
public class DrawingResult {
    public Image<Bgr, Byte> Images { get; private set; }
    public int Count {get; private set; }

    public DrawingResult(Image<Bgr, Byte> images, int count) {
       Images = images;
       Count = count;
    }
}
```

And in your method:

```
public static DrawingResult Draw(Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage, Image<Gray, byte> observedImage, out long matchTime)
{
    HomographyMatrix homography;
    VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
    VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
    Matrix<int> indices;
    Matrix<byte> mask;

    FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, out indices, out mask, out homography);

    //Draw the matched keypoints
    Image<Bgr, Byte> result = Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
       indices, new Bgr(255, 255, 255), new Bgr(255, 255, 255), mask, Features2DToolbox.KeypointDrawType.DEFAULT);

    int j = CvInvoke.cvCountNonZero(mask);
    return new DrawingResult(result, j);
}
```

And in the `main` method:

```
DrawingResult result = MyClass.Draw(...);
int count = result.Count;
Image<Bgr, Byte> images = result.Images;
```

Comment: I done your idea, but I got error in main(). Because class DrawingResult  wrote in another class named by DrawMatches.

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Easiest solution put the `DrawingResult` in an own class.

Comment: but my error in the main().

DrawingResult result = MyClass.Draw(...);

Comment: you have instead of `MyClass` use the class where `Draw is defined` --> which means `DrawingResult result = DrawMatches.Draw(...);`

Comment: OK. Thank you my brother

Comment: Sorry, I did not know, because I am newer in stackoverflow.

Can you help me in the following question:

[How to convert datatype of (Matrix<float>) to (array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369572/how-to-convert-matrixfloat-to-array)