# How to modify datatype of Matrix<float> to array?

Tags: c#, arrays, emgucv, type-conversion, surf

I am using Emgu CV (v2.4) with C#. In the following class. I need to modify the data type of the used column in the table to  array.

```
public void  FindSURF(Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage)
{
    VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;

    SURFDetector surfCPU = new SURFDetector(500, false);

    //extract features from the object image
    modelKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
    Matrix<float> modelDescriptors = surfCPU.DetectAndCompute(modelImage, null, modelKeyPoints);

}
```

the SURF feature extract and store in `Matrix<float> modelDescriptors` how can I modify this datatype to array?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998063/matrix-to-array-c-sharp

Comment: is it a `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the property from the `Matrix`:

```
float[] elements = modelDescriptors.Elements;
```

Comment: @Kurd what error? Add the current matrix, to your answer and also how the result should look

Comment: I am using Emgu CV (v2.4) with C# and read a collection images from specific folder, then I extracted SURF for all of them which are saved in _Matrix<float> modelDescriptors_. Finally, I have to modify the datatype of (modelDescriptors) to array and store in a postgresql database.

Comment: @Kurd I don't think that the method `DetectAndCompute` returns a `Matrix<float>` or am I wrong?

Comment: @Kurd What exception appears and please give a little example matrix

Comment: The SURF feature extract and store in `Matrix<float> modelDescriptors`, I want modify this `Matrix<float> modelDescriptors` to Array in next step. How can I do?